# SonarQube "Close this ConfigurableApplicationContext" in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have blocker issue "Close this "ConfigurableApplicationContext"" in main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

I've tried code from SonarQube example

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
    try
    {
        context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

but it closes the context right after starting.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: We are actually looking for feedback on this : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/Omg-sEBEneU/Gx8wdHGGAwAJ Feel free to weigh in so we can improve the rule.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue that SonarQube is reporting is a false positive and should be ignored. [SonarQube's FAQ](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions) lists some options for removing false positives:

> #### False-Positive and Won't Fix
>
> You can mark individual issues as False Positive or Won't Fix through the issues interface. However, this solution doesn't work across branches - you'll have to re-mark the issue False Positive for each branch under analysis. So an in-code approach may be preferable if multiple branches of a project are under analysis:
>
> #### //NOSONAR
>
> You can use the mechanism embedded in rules engine (//NOPMD...) or the generic mechanism implemented in SonarQube: put //NOSONAR at the end of the line of the issue. This will suppress the issue.
>
> #### Switch Off Issues
>
> You can review an issue to flag it as false positive directly from the user interface.

Comment: While //NOSONAR works, it disables all sonar checks although only for that line. Alternative is to specifically disable check for a single rule; which in this case you can do by adding `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2095")` on your main method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web application, the application context will be destroyed (I think by `ContextLoaderListener`, not sure), no explicit code is needed.

In the case of a command line application, the context must be destroyed manually, otherwise beans will not be destroyed properly - @PreDestroy methods will not be called. E.g:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
    return new ApplicationRunner() {
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

            try {
                doStuff();
            } finally {
                context.close();
            }
        }
```

I noticed this when a Cassandra session stayed open after my spring boot command line application has finished.

Answer (score 1):

I was always thinking, that it is false/positive.

But you can test this with a this few lines.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YourApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadApplicationContext() {
    }

    @Test
    public void applicationTest() {
        YourApplication.main(new String[] {});
    }

}
```

Now Sonar is saying, this is tested!
(Kudos goes out to: Robert @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775613/863403)