# How to JUnit Test Spring-Boot's Application.java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Apologize as this might seems to be an useless act, but is there any way we can actually do junit test on Spring-Boot(1.3.8.RELEASE)'s Application.java which this class does nothing but to start a Spring-boot application?

Given below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       try{
             SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }catch(Exception e){
             //code here
       }   
    }
}
```

Maybe i can try catching exception? but what else can i possibly test so that JUnit will test out SpringApplication.run()? any example is appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Usually, the following is sufficient to test that the application context starts up.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

However, if you want to directly test `Application.main`, you can also test it this way:

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Application.main(new String[]{
                "--spring.main.web-environment=false",
                "--spring.autoconfigure.exclude=blahblahblah",
                // Override any other environment properties according to your needs
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what covers the Sonar Test for it... thanks a lot, I hope more people will see this result!

Comment: If I remember correct if there is only one class with @SpringBootApplication then this one is taken and no further declaring is needed. Otherwise the tests just cannot know SpringBootApplication to launch.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe i can try catching exception? but what else can i possibly test
>   so that JUnit will test out SpringApplication.run()? any example is
>   appreciated. Thank you all!

Making the test fail if an exception is caught is here helpless as a thrown exception during a test has already as consequence to make the test fail (in error more precisely).
If you execute already test classes that load the whole spring boot context (`@SpringBootTest`) you don't need to write a test to check that it is correctly loaded.

You should test the `Application` class if it has some logic.
For example you could declare a method annotated with `@Before` that does some processing after the context is loaded and you would like to assert that the processing is done as it should done.   Other example : you could pass some arguments in the `main()` method and you would like to assert that the arguments are used by the method as expected.
All that is testable with `@SpringBootTest`.

If your `Application` class does nothing but :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {                   
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);         
 }
```

but you need all the same to cover the `main()` test method to be compliant with some coverage tool or organization, create an integration test for that, document it clearly and let the integration continuous does that because loading a Spring Boot application takes time. You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650268/how-to-test-main-class-of-spring-boot-application).