# What is the use of contextLoads method in Spring Boot Junit Testcases?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, testcase, spring-boot-test

This method is empty in all my JUnit test cases. What is the use of this method?

Sonarqube is complaining
"Add a nested comment explaining why this method is empty, throw an UnsupportedOperationException or complete the implementation."

I can bypass this by adding some comment but I just want to know why it is necessary.

Comment: It's just a placeholder so that there exists *some* test method. The "test" is that startup does not throw an exception.

Comment: check here. Maybe a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345526/should-i-test-the-main-method-of-spring-boot-application-and-how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I test the main() method of Spring Boot Application and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345526/should-i-test-the-main-method-of-spring-boot-application-and-how)

Answer (score 30):

When you build a Spring boot application using Spring Initializer. It auto creates a test class for you with `contextLoads` empty method.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationContextTest {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
  }
}
```

Note the use of `@SpringBootTest` annotation which tells Spring Boot to look for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication, for instance) and use that to start a Spring application context. Empty `contextLoads()` is a test to verify if the application is able to load Spring context successfully or not.

If sonarqube is complaining about the empty method then you can do something like this to verify your controller or service bean context:-

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationContextTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        assertThat(myController).isNotNull();
        assertThat(myService).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i use this to initialize class like @BeforeEach would do??

Comment: @RômuloSorato Could you please provide some example for better understanding. Here we are using `@SpringBootTest`, all the test runs in Spring context. If your class is independent and have no dependencies on other classes like utility class, you can initialize using constructor in `@BeforeEach`. If your class is dependent on other classes like service, controller, dao classes, you can initialize a class using `@Autowired` or mock class using `@MockBean`.

Answer (score -5):

Use different runner,

if you are using `SpringRunner.class`, use an alternative one such as `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` or `MockitoJunitRunner.class` rather then `SpringRunner.class`

```
@Runwith(SpringRunner.class)
 @Runwith(JUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @Runwith(MockitoJUnit4Runner.class)
 @Runwith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```