# How to write test case for Spring boot Application class with properties dependency - Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I followed the below StackOverflow page and wrote test case for Application class
[How to test main class of Spring-boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650268/how-to-test-main-class-of-spring-boot-application)

When I run my test case I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'http.client.connection.timeout' in value "${http.client.connection.timeout}"
.....
```

I have added @TestPropertySource("classpath:test-manifest.yml") in my test case.

**test-manifest.yml** has '**http.client.connection.timeout**'

**My Testcase**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.mypackage.Application;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-manifest.yml")
@SpringBootTest
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Application.main(new String[] {});
    }
}
```

How to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestPropertySource` does not support yaml configuration files.

Check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

> Supported File Formats
>
> Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "classpath:/com/example/test.properties" or "file:/path/to/file.xml".

See also
`TestPropertySourceUtils.addPropertiesFilesToEnvironment()`:

```
try {
    for (String location : locations) {
        String resolvedLocation = environment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(location);
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resolvedLocation);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(resource));
    }
}
```

`ResourcePropertySource` can only deal with .properties files and not .yml. In regular app, `YamlPropertySourceLoader` is registered and can deal with .

**Possible solutions:**

Either change your config to .properties or rely on profiles to load your test config.

Comment: I replaced "test-manifest.yml" with "application.properties" file. It is working as expected but my other test cases are working with ".yml" TestPropertySource.  Why it is working on my traditional test cases with MockMvc?

Comment: If younuse application.properties (or even application.yml) you don’t need TestPropertySource. It is difficult to guess what happens in your other tests without seeing them.