# Creating unit tests for SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-boot, junit, code-coverage

I have `SpringBootAplication` called MyApplication and one of the plugins that scans code coverage: `jacoco` complains about code coverage in this file.
My question is should I create unit test for this file, and if so what parts should I test?

```
package com.my.package.cdss;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650268/how-to-test-main-class-of-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exclude the classes from jacoco coverage configuration.

```
 <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/MyApplication.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
 </configuration>
```

Add this configuration in the jacoco dependency in POM XML